# Конвертация int to uint

Tags: c#, int

```
uint total;

public override void Operate(int val){

   total += (uint)val;

}

Operate(450);
Operate(-2000);
```

если прибавлять или вычитать при том что полученное число будет положительным, то никаких проблем, 
но если при вычитании на выходе число отрицательное, конвертация выдает какое-то лохматое число 4294942296, хотя должно быть например -250

```
при попытке сделать вот так
total += Convert.ToUint32(val);

дает ошибку
Value was either too large or too small for a UInt32.
```

как быть? total должен быть uint, а то что добавляется или вычитается там всегда маленькие значения и делать их uint не рационально

Comment: Перепишите `total += (uint)val;` как `total = (uint)(total + val);` Но всё равно вы делаете что-то странное

Comment: Что вы ожидаете при конвертации отрицательного числа в положительное? При конвертации -1 типа ``int`` в тип ``uint`` получается очень большое число. Нельзя взять и сконвертировать отрицательное число в положительное и ожидать правильный результат.

Comment: Вы пытаетесь впихнуть невпихуемое. uint не принимает отрицательных значений [`uint 0 to 4,294,967,295`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/integral-numeric-types)

Comment: Вы, похоже, считаете, что unit - это какой-то "большой int". На самом деле это просто "беззнаковое целое", и в памяти он занимает столько же, сколько и int, просто старший бит используется под само значение, а не под знак. Если вам нужно хранить большие суммы - возьмите decimal.

Comment: Мда .. вот что значит плохо поспать, совсем вылетело из головы что uint не имеет минуса =)
А я сижу ломаю голову, и так и сяк пытаюсь ))

Comment: ну что, господа, кто отважится написать ответ? :)

Comment: Возможно, вам нужен [тип `long` вместо `uint`](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/integral-numeric-types#characteristics-of-the-integral-types)

Answer (score 0):

```
uint total;

public override void Operate(int val){
   if (val < 0)
       total -= Math.Abs(val); или val*(-1)
   else
       total += val;

}

Operate(450);
Operate(-2000);
```

И лучше Operate поменять на Add:

```
Add(450);
Add(-2000);
```

Или сделать две функции:

```
uint total;

public override void Add(uint val){   
    total += val;
}

public override void Sub(uint val){   
    total -= val;
}
```

Нужно также не забывать о том, что можно выйти за предел самого числа. Поэтому можно сделать проверку собственную и проверку на исключение.
Так как проверку на исключение скучно делать, я покажу как делать ее вручную:

```
public override bool Add(uint val){   
    total += val;
    if (total < val) /*так как размер переменной val не больше размера total
        то при переполнении будет выполнятся это условие */
        return false;
    return true;
}

public override bool Sub(uint val){   
    total -= val;
    if (total > val) /*так как размер переменной val не больше размера total
        то при отрицательном переполнении будет выполнятся это условие */
        return false;
    return true;
}
```